# How to redirect a url to https without www in web.config?

Tags: iis, web-config, redirect

I want to do 301 permanent redirection of my domain from example.com to https://example.com (without www)

I am using the following rule:

```
            <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

But it always redirect me to https://www.example.com

Comment: Have you tried a different browser or in-private mode etc and see if you get the same behaviour?  As your setting a permanent redirection your browser might be caching an old response? (Generally i test redirects with a Temporary 307 then change to a Permanent 301 when sure it works). Also in your browsers "dev tools" there'll be an option to preserve requests. tick this and reload the page and it will record any redirections as well as the final document loaded. Lastly, have you tried replacing `{HTTP_HOST}` with `example.com`?

Comment: Its working now. You are right, it was caching problem of browser.